# Can a 17 year old take NSFW Commissions?

Tags: creative-writing, legal, short-story

As a 17 year old, am I allowed to write NSFW for commissions? If so, how extreme? Actual s*x, blowjobs, tits, etc lol, what would be allowed?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be a better fit for law stack exchange

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer and this is no legal advice. The following is my private opinion. Consult a lawyer, if you want to be safe.*

---

Yes, as far as I know a minor is allowed to create pornographic literature. After a quick internet search I come to the conclusion that there seems to be no law that forbids this.

The laws (in Western countries) forbid a variation of:

- the depiction of minors in pornography (text or image)*
- distributing pornography to minors
- child labor
- minors entering into certain kinds of contracts without parental consent

There is no law that forbids minors to earn money, as long as their work hours stay within some legal limits (e.g. a certain number of hours per week at a certain age and a limit to how physically taxing an occupation might be [e.g. no heavy lifting]).

What you need to find out for your jurisdiction is:

- Are you allowed to visit and use the platform where you sell your content (legally and by the TOS)?
- Are you allowed to enter into a contract with the publisher or platform that sells your work?
- Are you allowed to open a bank account or use some specific payment service? For example, Paypal requires you to be 18, I believe.

---

* This is an important distinction! As a minor, you can *create* pornography, but you cannot take pornographic selfies. That would be child pornography. And that is forbidden to create and own (and distribute, of course) in most jurisdictions, even if you are the depicted subject.

For that reason, do not write from the first person viewpoint! That might be interpreted as the protagonist ("you") being a minor. The fine distinction between narrator and author might not matter to a court of law.